# 'A end of line can't go after this """' in this applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I am writing an applescript to iterate thru all photo in the default album 'Photos'

[image]

Here is my script:

```
tell application "Photos"
  activate
  set alls = albums "Photos"
  repeat with photo in alls
    say photo.name
  end repeat
 end tell
```

Line 3. throws the following syntax error:

[image]

I am new to this language and I am unable to find an remedy to the incorrect syntax. Can any one point out what is amiss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the dictionary it helps to understand how each element is contained by other elements. To get the photos of all albums you have to loop through the media items of every album. This will get the filename of each photo.

```
tell application "Photos"
    activate
    set alls to every album
    repeat with photoAlbum in alls
        set photos to every media item in photoAlbum
        repeat with photo in photos
            get filename of photo
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```